# Two screens are messed up

Tags: android, android-activity, screen

I am done with my android app (so I thought) and loaded it on the market and hit publish only to find out that something went awry. The market gave me an error that had to do with my minSdkVersion code that I easily fixed. However, now 2 of my activities are small. This was not happening before I changed the code. All my other screens fit the phone screen fine, but these two do not fit. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you correctly filled out the `<supports-screens>` tag in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: that was the problem. <support-screens> was messed up. Thank you